# How to plot on 2 different scales on an axis in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot some data on x axis range [0:1] and y axis range [0:100], but on the x axis I have most of my data in range [0:0.1] and less data in the rest of the range.  I thus wanted to expand the [0:0.1] range.  I cannot use a logarithmic scale for the x axis as I have some data which is 0 and I cannot plot it if I use a logarithmic scale.  Is there a way for plotting this in Gnuplot?

Ideally I would want to apply a logarithmic scale to the x axis, but start my plot from 0. That would help me to cover all the data and highlight the [0:0.1] range as well.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, it is impossible to have a logarithmic scale with a 0.  I would use two graphs side by side, with separate x axes.  You can do this through `set multiplot layout 1,2`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Svante. An other option would be to introduce a second x-axis in the same plot. Then one x-axis would scale from 0:0.1 and the other would scale from 0:1. **Depending** on your data however this approach could be very confusing but I think especially if your data is primarily located between 0:0.1 this could work.